# No Duplicates in List Children

Tags: python

I'm working on a python script that extracts specific data from a very large html file and writes it to a CSV.  The data that is extracted is the order number, buyer's name, and email address.  I would like to not include any lines that would include a duplicate person, regardless if they have placed multiple orders.

Sample data:

```
['10001', 'Tom', 'tom@example.com']
['10002', 'Jane', 'jane@example.com']
['10003', 'Bob', 'bob@example.com']
```

The three lines above are already in a list called orders.  Then we come across this info:

```
number = '10004'
name = 'Jane'
email = 'jane@example.com'
```

I would like to NOT add that line to the list, based on the fact that the email address is already used in an existing line.

My code looks like this:

```
for order in orders:
    if [re.compile(r'+.'), re.compile(r'+.'), email] in rows: continue
    rows.append(number, name, email)
```

Comment: Why are you testing if a compiled regexp is in the list? That won't do a regexp search.

Comment: Obviously it doesn't work. Just gave it a try because other attempts weren't working, and I figured I'd demonstrate what I'm trying for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save all the names and email addresses in sets as you process the list, and check if the current name or email is in the set.

```
names = set()
emails = set()

for number, name, email in order:
    if name in names or email in emails:
        continue
    names.add(name)
    emails.add(email)
    rows.append([number, name, email])
```

Comment: I like it! Thanks!